# What's the difference between `export default xxx` and `export default xxx = fn`?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I use babel + webpack + react in my project. It works in Chrome, but it only works in the first way:

`request.js`

```
const fetch = (options) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ...
    $.ajax(options);
 })
}

export default fetch;
```

If I use `export default fetch = fn` I will get a error.

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [["es2015", { "modules": false }], "stage-2", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-assign",
    // "transform-strict-mode"
    // ["transform-runtime", {"helpers": false,"polyfill": false,"regenerator": true}],
    "transform-node-env-inline",
    //"transform-remove-strict-mode",
    //"transform-strict-mode",
    ["react-transform", {
      "transforms": [{
        "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
        "imports": ["react"],
        "locals": ["module"]
      }, {
        "transform": "react-transform-catch-errors",
        "imports": ["react", "redbox-react"]
      }]
    }]
  ],

  "env": {
    "development": {
       "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
    }
  }
}
```

So, why? thanks.

Comment: Because you cannot assign to an undeclared variable in modules.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's not valid JS syntax.

Try this:

```
export default function fetch() {
  ...
}
```